# Removing an infinite collection of elements from $\mathbb{Q}$ and testing density in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

I know that $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$.

Is there an example of a subset $S \subset \mathbb{Q}$ that is dense in $\mathbb{R}$ such that $\mathbb{Q}\backslash S$ is infinite?

Essentially, can I remove an infinite collection of elements from $\mathbb{Q}$ and still have a set that is dense in $\mathbb{R}$?

My initial thought (seemingly supported by related topics on StackExchange) is that you can only remove countably many elements from $\mathbb{Q}$, but the resulting density has to be tested in any case. Obviously, you can't just remove any element from $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: How about rationals with denominators of the form $2^n$ for some $n$

Comment: Generalizing the idea given in the comment by @QC_QAOA, $\mathbb Q$ is the union of a countably infinite collection of pairwise disjoint sets, each of which is dense in $\mathbb R.$ Moreover, the sets can be defined very explicitly -- no abstract existence-proved-by-contradicting-nonexistence methods are needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take $S=\mathbb Q\setminus \mathbb N$ which is dense in $\mathbb R$, also $\mathbb Q\setminus S=\mathbb N$ is infinite.